# Which Windows version corresponds to WINVER = 0x0606?

Tags: winapi

WinUser.h defines the following constants

```
#if(WINVER >= 0x0606)
#define IDC_PIN            MAKEINTRESOURCE(32671)
#define IDC_PERSON         MAKEINTRESOURCE(32672)
#endif /* WINVER >= 0x0606 */
```

but I can't find which Windows version `0x0606` corresponds to. I checked [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt) but there is no exact match. It looks like newer than Windows 8.1 (`0x0603`) and older than Windows 10 (`0x0A00`).

Is there a comprehensive list?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt?view=msvc-170

Comment: I referenced that link in my original post. There is no mention of the constant I am asking about.

Comment: Likely it’s some early build of windows 10

Comment: One API that's guarded behind this particular value is [`GetWindowDpiHostingBehavior`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowdpihostingbehavior). In its requirements section it states Windows 10 as the "Minimum supported client" and Windows Server 2016 as the "Minimum supported server", so I'm guessing that `0x0606` refers to Windows Server 2016.

Comment: @IInspectable Windows Server 2016 falls under Windows v10.0.  There was no Windows v6.6, it jumped from v6.3 (Windows 8.1/Windows Server 2012 R2) to v10.0 (Windows 10/Windows Server 2016). Doesn't mean there couldn't have been internal builds while they were preparing for Windows 10, though.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I will assume that `0x0606` represents an internal build post-Windows 8.1 and pre-Windows 10. From a user perspective, this implies that the use of the above constants requires Windows 10.